# Left-Click Spam on Hold Down [ Scripting Tools ]

Tags: 18.04, scripts, software-recommendation, automation

I was wondering if there was a tool that allowed you to do basic scripting with mouse clicks and etc. like AHK/AutoHotkey.  Something like while (Left Click down) { Click Sleep 100} return and optionally a key to suspend/disable the hotkey.

Is there anything like this for Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

After installing a bunch of automation tools like SikuliX, xdotool, Autokey, Easytouch, etc. I finally came across a tutorial detailing how to write a python script to spam left click on hotkey toggle (credit to: [How to write an Autoclicker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eamTeszpeZ4) ) It isn't exactly what I wanted, but I'm sure I'll get it with enough tinkering.